# How to terminate EC2 instance from user-data script on the instance itself immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have some user-data script that configures some applications on My EC2 instances.
I want a new instance to be terminated ***immediately*** if a certain condition occurs during that script run.

I've tried both the following commands in the script. However, the termination does not occur until ***10+ minutes after*** the command is issued.

```
aws autoscaling terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group --instance-id $instanceid --no-should-decrement-desired-capacity


aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $instanceid
```

Is there any way to force the termination to occur sooner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than asking the Amazon EC2 service to terminate an instance, you can simply **call the Operating System** and tell it to Stop the instance:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

(The `-h` tells it to 'halt' the virtual hardware, which signals to the EC2 instance that the computer is now turned off, much like your home computer turns itself off after a 'Shutdown' command.)

Depending upon the configured [Shutdown Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior) of the instance, it will either move into the `Stopped` or `Terminated` state.

I notice that you are using Auto Scaling. If Auto Scaling notices an instance is stopped/terminated, it will automatically launch a replacement. However, it might take a few minutes to detect this and launch a replacement.

Comment: I believe you explicitly do no want `-h` according to the AWS docs.

Comment: "The halt command does not initiate a shutdown. If used, the instance does not terminate; instead, it places the CPU into HLT and the instance remains running."

Comment: Hi @jordanm! My experience is the opposite. If the `-h` command is _not_ used, then the operating system stops, but the instance does not stop. I just tested this by launching an EC2 instance, then issuing the `sudo shutdown now -h` command. Soon after, the instance moved into a `Stopped` state. Please note that the documentation you quoted refers to the `halt` command, not the `shutdown` command.

Comment: Its not something i've tested in a while, so I trust your results. The manpage for the shutdown command says that `-h` causes it to behave like the `halt` command instead of the `poweroff` command which is the default. The quote I posted earlier came from this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/terminating-instances.html#terminating-instances-console

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back. Yes, I am using auto scaling, which doesn't trigger a replacement soon enough due to this 10+ min termination delay. With this delay resolved, the turnaround will be much quicker.

Comment: By the way, if the instance is windows, would you use `Stop-Computer -ComputerName localhost`?

Comment: A bit of searching suggests you can just use `shutdown /s`, but I haven't tried it.